# PHP - Post JQUERY Value to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm working on a chat, and i'm stuck on the last part of my chat... the text input part. 
I had to use some copy and past to create a jquery code to my textarea:

SHIFT+ENTER = New line 
Press Enter = Submit

Here is my jquery code: http://jsfiddle.net/McH8q/35/

My plan now is to use php to send the text value from jquery to MySQL. 
The problem is that I have never combined php with jquery.

Is there a easy way to do something like this:

```
<?php 

$text = $_POST['JQUERY TEXT FROM TEXTAREA'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your javascript to:

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
        if (!event.shiftKey) $('#testForm').submit();
});

$('#testForm').on('submit', function() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = $.trim($("textarea").val());
    if (text != "") {
         $.ajax("http://yourdomain/chat.php?text=" + text);
         $('textarea').val('');
    }
});
});
```

then create a file chat.php there you can get users message using

```
$msg = $_GET['text'];
```

then can connect with database and save value in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use that code on another php page, you will lose your Jquery variables because Jquery/Javascript is client based code, I recommend validating the value with jquery and after the jquery is done and validated, add a attribute to your html code (with jquery): `post="x.php"`.

Hope this gives you an idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery ajax. 
When you want to send the data to the php file use this syntax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(){
     < what you want to do if the text was posted successfully >
},
  error: function(){
     < what you want to do if the post failed >
}
});
Where url  = path to php file ,
      data = a javascript object, ( you can use {text:textvariable} )
      textvariable = the variable with the text from chat.
```

and in the php file you will get the POST request with the attrib "text" ( the post request will have all the data sent in the "data" object in the above code, 
so for the above code you should have `$_POST['text']` to get it at the php file(Backend) 
Alternatively, You could also send a get request replacing the "POST" with a "GET"

Refer [Jquery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)